# How to use user input in function in swiftui?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a View, in which the user is able to enter some text into a TextField. I want to be able to get the text, which was entered in the TextField and use this value inside of a struct. The concept of the app, is that it shows the elevation degree of the sun. To be able to do this, it is scraping the values from a WebPage. However to make this app dynamic, the user has to be able to edit the url (you can change location, date etc in the url). I thought this would be fairly easy, since I only have to get some text, and edit a url before the url is being loaded. I have been able to pass the value into a view, however I need it in a struct. Maybe the whole "layout of my code is wrong, maybe I should get the data and draw the function in a view? I don't know. This is my first time coding with swift.

I want to change the latitude var.

This is my code:

View 1 (Input):

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var latitude:String = ""
    @Published var page = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var value1: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        if value1.page == 0{
            VStack{
            TextField("", text: $value1.latitude)
            Button(action:{ value1.page = 1}){
                Text("To next view")
            }.frame(width: 300, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        }
    } else {
        elevationGraph()
    }
}
}
```

View 2 (Graph)

```
struct getHtml { 
    var url = URL(string: "https://midcdmz.nrel.gov/apps/spa.pl?syear=2020&smonth=1&sday=1&eyear=2020&emonth=1&eday=1&otype=0&step=60&stepunit=1&hr=12&min=0&sec=0&latitude=\(latitude)&longitude=10.757933&timezone=1.0&elev=53&press=835&temp=10&dut1=0.0&deltat=64.797&azmrot=180&slope=0&refract=0.5667&field=0")
    
    func loadData(from url: URL?) -> String {
        guard let url = url else {
            return "nil"
        }

        let html = try! String(contentsOf: url, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        
        return html
        
    }
}



struct elevationFunction: Shape {

var url: URL? //This only works in views, is there a way to do it in shape structs?
    
    let html = getHtml.init().loadData(from: getHtml.init().url)

    private func dbl1() -> Double {
        
        let leftSideOfTheValue = "0:00:00,"
        
        let rightSideOfTheValue = "\(month)/\(day)/\(year),1:00:00,"
        
        guard let leftRange = html.range(of: leftSideOfTheValue) else {
            print("cant find left range")
            return 0
        }
        
        guard let rightRange = html.range(of: rightSideOfTheValue) else {
            print("cant find right range")
            return 0
        }
        
        let rangeOfTheValue = leftRange.upperBound..<rightRange.lowerBound
        
        return Double(html[rangeOfTheValue].dropLast()) ?? 90
    }

    
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {

        var path = Path()
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: (125 - (90-dbl1()))))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 120, y: (125 - (90-45))))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: (125 - (90-dbl1()))))
    
        var scale = (rect.height / 350) * (9/10)
        var xOffset = (rect.width / 6)
        var yOffset = (rect.height / 2)
        
        return path.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)).applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: xOffset, y: yOffset))
        
        
    }
}

struct elevationGraph: View {
        var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { geometry in 
                ZStack {
                    elevationFunction().stroke(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.yellow, Color.red]), startPoint: .top , endPoint: .bottom), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 6.0)).aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    
                }
            .frame(width: 600, height: 800, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you say that the URL only works in Views.  You can pass it as a parameter to a Shape as well.  In your code it would look like `elevationFunction(url: yourURL)` (PS -- common practice is to always capitalize your data types; eg classes, structs) -- `ElevationFunction`, or better `ElevationShape`

Comment: I have done it like that `var url1: URL?` int he second view, and passed it like you said, but now I get the error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCES (code=2, address=0x7ffee73ceff8)" on the line were I get the html`'let html = getHtml.init().loadData(from: elevationFunction.init().url1)` It doesn't show, before I run the program, but as soon, as I click next view, the program crashes and shows this error.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you can pass a parameter to a `Shape` just like you can a regular `View`:

```
elevationFunction(url: yourURL)
```

Best practice would be to capitalize this and name it ...Shape as well:
`elevationFunction` becomes `ElevationShape`

Regarding your second question in the comment, first, you may want to fix the naming of `getHtml` for the same reason as above -- uncapitalized, it looks like a variable name.  Maybe something like `DataLoader`.

Regarding the crash, you have some circular logic going on -- you call `getHtml.init()` and then pass a parameter that is again derived from `getHtml.init()` again.  Why not just call `getHtml()` and have it `loadData` from its own internal `URL` property?

There's a larger problem at work, though, which is that you've declared `html` as a `let` property on your `Shape`, which is going to get recreated every time your `Shape` is rendered.  So, on every render, with your current code, you'll create 2 new `getHtmls` and attempt to load the data (which very well may not actually have time to load the URL request).  This very well could be blocking the first render of the `Shape` as well and is almost certainly causing your crash somewhere in the circular and repetitive logic going on.

Instead, you might want to consider moving your URL request to `onAppear` or as part of an `ObservableObject` where you can have a little more control of when and how often this data gets loaded.  Here's a good resource on learning more about loading data using `URLSession` and SwiftUI: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/sending-and-receiving-codable-data-with-urlsession-and-swiftui